# Problems with Employee Summary at the end not showing

Tags: java, c++, architecture

I had everything working, and when I went to check it before I turned it in, something messed up and I can't get it to run the Employee Summary at the end. Can someone direct me to what part I am missing here? I also keep getting 3 warnings C$@$$ "=" conversion from double to float possible loss of data ? lines 99, 101, and 109?:

```
    // ConsoleApplication29.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    //
    //CLASS DECLARATION SECTION
    //
    class EmployeeClass
     {
    public:
    void ImplementCalculations(string EmployeeName, int hours, double wage);
    void DisplayEmployInformation(void);
    void Addsomethingup (EmployeeClass Emp1, EmployeeClass Emp2, EmployeeClass Emp3);
    string EmployeeName ;
    int hours ;
    float wage ;
    float basepay ;
    int overtime_hours ;
    float overtime_pay ;
    float overtime_extra ;
    float iTotal_salaries ;
    float iIndividualSalary ;
    int iTotal_hours ;
    int iTotal_OvertimeHours ;
    };

    int main()
    {   system("cls"); 

    cout << "\nWelcome to the Employee Pay Center\n\n" ;

    EmployeeClass Emp1;
    EmployeeClass Emp2;
    EmployeeClass Emp3;


    cout << "Enter the first employee's name      = ";
    cin >> Emp1.EmployeeName;
    cout << "\nEnter the hours worked               = ";
    cin >> Emp1.hours;
    cout << "\nEnter their hourly wage         = ";
    cin >> Emp1.wage;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter the second employee's name      = ";
    cin >> Emp2.EmployeeName;
    cout << "\nEnter the hours worked               = ";
    cin >> Emp2.hours;
    cout << "\nEnter their hourly wage         = ";
    cin >> Emp2.wage;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter the third employee's name      = ";
    cin >> Emp3.EmployeeName;
    cout << "\nEnter the hours worked               = ";
    cin >> Emp3.hours;
    cout << "\nEnter their hourly wage         = ";
    cin >> Emp3.wage;


    cout << endl;
    Emp1.ImplementCalculations(Emp1.EmployeeName, Emp1.hours, Emp1.wage);
    Emp2.ImplementCalculations(Emp2.EmployeeName, Emp2.hours, Emp2.wage);
    Emp3.ImplementCalculations(Emp3.EmployeeName, Emp3.hours, Emp3.wage);


    system ("pause");
    return 0;


    //This section you will send all three objects to a function that will add up the the         following information:
    //- Total Employee Salaries 
    //- Total Employee Hours
    //- Total Overtime Hours

    //The format for this function is the following:
    //- Define a new object.
    //- Implement function call [objectname.functionname(object name 1, object name 2, object name 3)]


    } //End of Main Function


    void EmployeeClass::ImplementCalculations (string EmployeeName, int hours, double wage)    {
    //Initialize overtime variables
    overtime_hours=0;
    overtime_pay=0;
    overtime_extra=0;

    if (hours > 40) 
    {       

    basepay = 40 * wage;
    overtime_hours = hours - 40;
    overtime_pay = wage * 1.5;
    overtime_extra = overtime_hours * overtime_pay;
    iIndividualSalary = overtime_extra + basepay;

    }   // if (hours > 40)
    else
    {   

    basepay = hours * wage;
    iIndividualSalary = basepay;

    }   
    DisplayEmployInformation ();

    } //End of Primary Function

    void EmployeeClass::DisplayEmployInformation () 
    {
    // This function displays all the employee output information.

    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "Employee Name ............. = " << EmployeeName << endl;
    cout << "Base Pay .................. = " << basepay << endl;
    cout << "Hours in Overtime ......... = " << overtime_hours << endl;
    cout << "Overtime Pay Amount......... = " << overtime_extra << endl;
    cout << "Total Pay ................. = " << iIndividualSalary << endl;

    } // END OF Display Employee Information

    void EmployeeClass::Addsomethingup (EmployeeClass Emp1, EmployeeClass Emp2,     EmployeeClass Emp3)
    {

   iTotal_salaries = 0;
   iTotal_hours = 0;
   iTotal_OvertimeHours = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
     {
        cout << "\n\n";
        cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
        cout << "%%%% EMPLOYEE SUMMARY DATA%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
        cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
        cout << "%%%% Total Employee Salaries ..... =" << iTotal_salaries << endl;
        cout << "%%%% Total Employee Hours ........ =" << iTotal_hours << endl;
        cout << "%%%% Total Overtime Hours......... =" << iTotal_OvertimeHours << endl;
        cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
        cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
     }
        system("PAUSE");
        return;
     } // End of function
```

Comment: Sorry, warning was C4244.

Comment: You should really cut the code down to a sensible testcase. Without line numbers it's pretty hard to figure out which line is 99...

Comment: Also I would remove the tags that do not apply. I know c# was deleted but c and java should go as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it numbered. It's the If/Else Statement in the code.

Comment: PS: Your indentation is bogus, which is possibly what threw you off. Consider finding a code editor or an IDE that maintains indentation for you, it'll be easier to spot errors like this.

Answer (score 2):

You never call `Addsomethingup`, so it won't ever print the summary. Converting a double to a float of course loses precision. Use either float or double for all of your variables consistently (i.e. don't mix those unless you have a good reason not to, which you probably don't here).

Comment: Would this be something I call in the Declaration Section I made in the beginning?

Comment: No, declarations don't call anything. I think you should also get a book on C++ basics, or a course. Functions call other functions, in this case `main()` calls some (`ImplementCalculations`) ... but a call to `Addsomethingup` doesn't appear anywhere, so it won't execute.

Comment: How do I start to fix the issue with converting double or float for the variables? I am really clumsy with this part. We spent about 4 days on this about a week ago, and it didn't seem like enough to understand. Any helpful sources would be greatly appreciated since I really do have an interest in this subject.:-)

Comment: Just don't use `float` at all. Use `double` everywhere. Or vice versa. `float` has fewer bits compared to `double` so converting from `double` to `float` might lose some of the least significant digits in the number.

Comment: Yes! Changing everything to double worked! I am so appreciative. I'm trying to find more about this because the school book I had was downloaded from online, we only downloaded the chapters we needed so I didn't have a chapter that talked about this topic much. I just found one online I just bought to help me more. The only thing I'm still trying to figure out is how to get the employee summary to show at the end. I'm trying to take into consideration with what http://stackoverflow.com/users/2968458/mornfall was telling me.

Comment: I'm so appreciative. I wish I would have found this site and you guys sooner in this course!

Answer (score 1):

(1) I compiled/ran this under MSVC 2010 and didn't get the type warnings.  However, the warning issues are likely because you are mixing types -- wage, basepay and overtime_pay are all type float, and you are doing calculations that use variables with type int (the literal 40 and hours) 
    a - use 40f instead of 40  (uses a floating point constant instead of int) and
    b - use static_cast(hours) instead of just hours in those statements
    c - consider using type double instead of float - you get better precision with double than type float anyways.

and as Mornfall noted, you never call the AddSomethingUp member function.

The only references to that function are the prototype header in the class description and the actual code itself -- you don't invoke it anywhere.

You can build functional code 'till the cows come home, but unless you actually tell the program, somewhere, to run it, it won't get executed.  You need to invoke it after you have processed the employee data and before you have executed the 'return' statement from main.

This was written using some version of Visual Studio the dead give-away for that are the following lines:

```
// ConsoleApplication29.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.`
//
#include "stdafx.h"
```

did you try running it under the debugger in order to se what code was invoked?

Comment: I'm sorry you guys. I had to leave. I've been juggling this and having a loved one in the hospital.  I'm trying to figure out where to declare it, but I'm having difficulty. I debugged it, but that's the only thing that is coming up now is that it is not declared outside the class. I don't understand?

Comment: Hello, the only issue I am having now is that it says Expected a declaration on the "{" ...right after              "// END OF Display Employee Information"